# How to traverse all fields of C++ class?

Tags: c++, c++11, reflection, visitor-pattern

I develop small reflection library for studying purpose. I want to traverse all fields of some C++ class. There is guarantee, that this class implement `reflect` function. The full example of such class is:

```
struct some_class
{
    char field1;
    bool field2;

    some_class()
        : field1(0)
        , field2(0)
    {
    }
};

template<class proc>
void reflect(proc& p, some_class& sc)
{
    reflect(p, sc.field1, "field1");
    reflect(p, sc.field2, "field2");
}
```

I want to traverse  all the fields of this class and perform some action for each of field. For example, I may print field or serialize it.

I think I need to implement `Visitor pattern`. I also think that the `Generic lambdas` (С++ 14) help me too.

```
auto lambda = [](auto x, auto y) {return x + y;};
```

I do not know how to solve my task. I look forward to any advice.

Note, that the signature of `reflect function` is immutable. I cannot change it.

Comment: @nestedloop, no, It does not. The signature of `reflect function` is const. I can not change it.

Comment: @Barry, why you decide, that my question is duplicate?

Comment: Because you want to know how "to traverse all fields of some C++ class" -- which is exactly what that question asked and has answers for?

Comment: @Barry, but my case is other. I cannot use `REFLECTABLE macro` from that example.